# Mysql finding results not present in jointable

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got a mysql question that I haven't been able to figure out. Its a little bit different than the other questions I've found here on SO.

I've got three tables

```
users
____________
ID  name
1   John
2   Mike
3   Susie

tasks
___________
ID  Name
1   Brush Teeth
2   Shower
3   Check Email

users_tasks
_____________________
ID  user_id   task_id 
1   1         1
2   1         2
3   1         3
4   2         1
5   2         2
6   3         1
```

Im trying to find out what users haven't completed what tasks yet. I would like the result set to look like this:

```
user_id    task_id
__________________
2          3
3          2
3          3
```

The closest I have come is this query, which only gives me users that haven't completed at least one of the tasks, but doesn't give me the task.

```
select * FROM users 
right JOIN  users_tasks on users.id = users_tasks.user_id
right JOIN  tasks on users_tasks.task_id = tasks.id
where tasks.id is null
```

I cant figure out how to return duplicate users and tasks based on what is missing form the join table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is just to require that the entry is not in your completed tasks table:

```
select * from users, tasks
where not exists (
    select * from users_tasks
    where users.id = users_tasks.user_id and tasks.id = users_tasks.task_id
);
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | name  | id   | name        |
+------+-------+------+-------------+
|    3 | susie |    2 | Shower      |
|    2 | mike  |    3 | Check Email |
|    3 | susie |    3 | Check Email |
+------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a set representing the cartesian product of the `users` and `tasks` tables. This is what would be the result if every user had done every task. Then do a left join with the actual `users_tasks` table and filter for null to get the missing items:

```
select sub.* 
from (
    select u.id user_id, t.id task_id 
    from users u, tasks t
) sub 
left join users_tasks ut on sub.user_id = ut.user_id and sub.task_id = ut.task_id
where ut.ID is null;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer works great.  I chose steffens because with my result set its running just a bit faster.